# WPF DataGrid - Default Values for Generated Objects

Tags: wpf

I wanna bind the data grid control to a collection property in my MVVM model in such way that when new rows are added the model itself is set to a property of each object generated by the datagrid. The purpose of doing this is to create a two-way one to many relationship between the model and its child collection items so each item can be aware of the parent model.

How to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "the model is passed to the constructor" what do you mean?  In my experience Model refers specifically to the data object domain in the program.  If you are talking about having a Model Parent Class that has Children in a collection, that should be fairly straightforward.  Please elucidate.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the DataGrid's New Record Row to add items.  I am unsure of how to do what you want with that, however, what you can do is add a button to create a new item, bind the buttons command property to a command on your ViewModel, and construct from there.  Just have an overloaded constructor that takes an argument.

It occurs to me that you might be able to do it otherwise.  You would have to make what ever object you are wishing to reference from the new object visible to it.  You could do it thusly:

1. In your MainWindow (or App.xaml) codebehind, create and expose a
   property to hold the current Model object.
2. Whenever the current Model object changes, reflect that change in the exposed property.
3. In the constructor for your child object, look for that property.
4. If it is not null, then assign it to the appropriate Child
   navigation property.